# I have problems when i use Flutter GetXController

Tags: flutter, controller, widget, flutter-getx

This was the error I was getting when I ran the app.

```
The following message was thrown building GetX<WeeklyChartController>(controller: Instance of 'WeeklyChartController', tag: null, has builder, dirty, state: GetXState<WeeklyChartController>#6a0aa(controller: Instance of 'WeeklyChartController')):
      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

The relevant error-causing widget was
GetX<WeeklyChartController>

A RenderFlex overflowed by 99403 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
```

This was the code for it

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:english_app/component/weekly_exercise_chart.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class WeeklyChartController extends GetxController {
  final String userId;

  WeeklyChartController({
    required this.userId,
  });

  var data = RxList<WeekDayData>([
    WeekDayData('Mon', 0),
    WeekDayData('Tue', 0),
    WeekDayData('Wed', 0),
    WeekDayData('Thu', 0),
    WeekDayData('Fri', 0),
    WeekDayData('Sat', 0),
    WeekDayData('Sun', 0),
  ]);

  // var total = 0;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    getData();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    getData();
    super.onReady();
  }

  void getData() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    int currentWeekday = now.weekday;

    DateTime startOfWeekError =
        now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday - 1)).toUtc();
    DateTime endOfWeekError = startOfWeekError
        .add(Duration(days: 6))
        .add(Duration(hours: 23, minutes: 59, seconds: 59))
        .toUtc();

    DateTime _start = DateTime(startOfWeekError.year, startOfWeekError.month,
        startOfWeekError.day, 0, 0);
    DateTime _end = DateTime(endOfWeekError.year, endOfWeekError.month,
        endOfWeekError.day, 23, 59, 59);

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('progress')
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'Completed')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
        .where('timestamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
        .where('timestamp', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end)
        .get();

    // total = querySnapshot.size;

    data.assignAll([
      WeekDayData('Mon', 0),
      WeekDayData('Tue', 0),
      WeekDayData('Wed', 0),
      WeekDayData('Thu', 0),
      WeekDayData('Fri', 0),
      WeekDayData('Sat', 0),
      WeekDayData('Sun', 0),
    ]);

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      DateTime timestamp =
          (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['timestamp'].toDate();
      int weekday = timestamp.weekday;
      data[weekday - 1].value++;
    });

    update();
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:english_app/controllers/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:english_app/controllers/weekly_chart_controller.dart';
import 'package:english_app/utils/color_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class WeeklyExerciseChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeeklyExerciseChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WeeklyExerciseChart> createState() => _WeeklyExerciseChartState();
}

class _WeeklyExerciseChartState extends State<WeeklyExerciseChart> {
  AuthController _controller = Get.put(AuthController());
  // late WeeklyChartController controller;
  late String uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    uid = _controller.getUserId();
    // controller = Get.put(WeeklyChartController(userId: uid));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<WeeklyChartController>(
        init: WeeklyChartController(userId: uid),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                'This week, You finished',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    color: hexStringToColor('3A476C'),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 10),
                child: Text(
                  'Total : ',
                  // + controller.total.toString()
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 180,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: SfCartesianChart(
                    backgroundColor: hexStringToColor('6E6BFC'),
                    plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                    borderColor: Colors.transparent,
                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0.1),
                        majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
                        axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                      majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0.1),
                      majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
                      axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
                      labelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent, fontSize: 0),
                    ),
                    series: <SplineAreaSeries<WeekDayData, String>>[
                      SplineAreaSeries<WeekDayData, String>(
                          dataSource: controller.data,
                          xValueMapper: (WeekDayData sales, _) => sales.day,
                          yValueMapper: (WeekDayData sales, _) => sales.value,
                          cardinalSplineTension: 3,
                          splineType: SplineType.cardinal,
                          gradient: const LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 252, 0.7),
                              Color.fromRGBO(95, 92, 250, 1),
                            ],
                          ),
                          borderWidth: 3,
                          markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(
                            isVisible: true,
                          ),
                          dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(
                              isVisible: true,
                              useSeriesColor: true,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              labelAlignment: ChartDataLabelAlignment.top)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]),
          );
        });
  }
}

class WeekDayData {
  final String day;
  late int value;

  WeekDayData(this.day, this.value);
}
```